# Virtualbox Kernel not working

Tags: drivers, kernel, virtualbox

I had the brilliant idea of switching from windows to Ubuntu 20.04, however i soon realized that Adobe does not support Linux. I downloaded Vmware but it had an issue with Kernel. Not knowing how to deal with it i downloaded Virtualbox instead, however, I had the same issue. How would I go about solving the issue?

probelem message:
**Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
'/sbin/vboxconfig'
as root.
If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for more information.
where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT**

Comment: Turn off Secure Boot in your BIOS. Be happy :-)

Comment: Thank you man, you're a saint!

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install build-essential

Will install kernel headers and such